# DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol getting this exception

Tags: android

```
 And some times i'm getting java.net.MalFormedURLException what's the reason behind this and how can i resolve this..

My code is as follows..


SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                "http://w3devadv.liveproj.com  /api/apiRequest.php?Method=getdealdetails&DealId=2&SessionId=EA3JQ0RZJT4e66223143fc5");

        /**
         * Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler )
         */
        DealsHandler myXMLHandler = new DealsHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));


In handler i'm writing the following code in startelement  

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentElement = true;
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("data")) {
        dealsdata = new DealsData();
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("dealdetails")) {
        deals = new Deals();
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        deals.title = attributes.getLocalName(0);
    }

i'm getting the above said exception how can i resolve this.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because.....

```
"This exception is thrown when a program attempts to create an URL from an
incorrect specification."
```

Answer (score 1):

before passing the string to url 
you can **Convert the string to Standard URL format**

this way..

```
String url = new String(str.trim().replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26")
.replace(",", "%2c").replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29")
.replace("!", "%21").replace("=", "%3D").replace("<", "%3C")
.replace(">", "%3E").replace("#", "%23").replace("$", "%24")
.replace("'", "%27").replace("*", "%2A").replace("-", "%2D")
.replace(".", "%2E").replace("/", "%2F").replace(":", "%3A")
.replace(";", "%3B").replace("?", "%3F").replace("@", "%40")
.replace("[", "%5B").replace("\\", "%5C").replace("]", "%5D")
.replace("_", "%5F").replace("`", "%60").replace("{", "%7B")
.replace("|", "%7C").replace("}", "%7D"));
```

You can use this function anywhere you are fetching URL and using it, so you can overcome the Error and make your string work.

i know you accepted the answer but this could also help other also i think
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://w3devadv.liveproj.com  /api/apiRequest.php?Method=getdealdetails&DealId=2&SessionId=EA3JQ0RZJT4e66223143fc5"
```

It is probably due to the space in the URL.